# How to vertically offset a wellPanel from the very top?

Tags: r, shiny, offset

I have a layout with just one row and one column in a wellPanel. My goal is to offset this panel vertically. At the moment it is "glued" to the very top, but should move down by some centimeters.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  wellPanel(fluidRow(column(width = 11, align = "center", h3("I need to move south!")))))

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: You can add `br()`, to add new line on top of `wellPanel()`...

Comment: Ok, that's a compromise. However, I would prefer something that gives me more flexiblity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap a `wellPanel()` in an `absolutePanel()`

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
   absolutePanel(top = "50%", left = 20, width = "97.5%", 
            wellPanel(
              fluidRow(
                column(
                  width = 12,
                  align = "center", h3("I am at the centre!")
                )
              )
            )
 )
)

server <- function(input, output){}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```